# How to iterate over String(char[])

Tags: java, string

I read the content of one file into `String(char[]) content`:

```
8264,1
28462,1
15836,1
```

Then I want to multiply second column by 5 and append another file with processed values:

```
8264,5
28462,5
15836,5
```

The problem is with iterating over `content`. If I iterate as shown below, then obviously I get chars like `8`, `2`, `6`, `4`, etc., but not lines `8264,5`.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filew.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int k = 0; k < content.length(); k++) 
{
    char c = content.charAt(k);
    //multiply second column by 5
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate line by line I would recommend a Scanner.

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(...file/stream...);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(...your file/stream/string...);
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    String[] parts = line.split(",");
    int first = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int second = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    second *= 5;
    pw.println(first + "," + second);
}
sc.close();
pw.close();
```

Comment: One question. It looks like it does not append the CSV file. It just rewrite it. How to append the file?